# SQL order by part of string (Postgresql)

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

I need some help with SQL sort query creation. I have data like

```
ref_num
24534535_R
11789999_S
34543049_S
23476243_R
45737458_S
```

I need to sort that data based on the last string (R first, then S)

How to sort it using postgresql?

I tried using substring and still not work

Comment: `ORDER BY reverse(column_name)` ? https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/reverse-function.php

Comment: Upvote to @bassxzero for elegance, but if you want to sort first by suffix and then by the number `order by right(ref_num, 1), ref_num` or more broadly `order by split_part(refnum, '_', 2), ref_num`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`right(string text, n integer) → text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.34.1.1.1):

```sql
select * from some_table order by right(ref_num, 1);
```